# Argument principle for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis

Let $f,g$ be entire functions, then the argument principle teaches us that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}} g(z) \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$$
is equal to $g$ evaluated at the zeros of $f.$

Now, let us assume that $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ is matrix-valued and holomorphic.

If $f$ is diagonal, then it follows from the above theorem that 
$$\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}} g(z) Df(z)f(z)^{-1} dz\right)$$
is precisely $g$ evaluated at the singular points of $f$, i.e. the points $z$ for which $\operatorname{det}(f(z))=0$ times $2-\text{rank}(f(z))$ at those points.

I ask: If $f$ is now not assumed to be diagonal, but only self-adjoint, does this statement hold true, i.e.
$$\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}} g(z) Df(z)f(z)^{-1} dz\right)=\sum_{z \in \mathbb{C}; \operatorname{det}(f(z))=0} g(z) \text{rank}(2-f(z)).$$

An obvious approach would be to use that $f$ is diagonalizable and the properties of the trace, but in this case the unitary transform also depends on $z$, so a bit more care seems to be needed.

Comment: Thanks for having accepted my answer. I see that you are a newcomer on MO. In principle, you should also vote for it. Otherwise, that looks strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write instead
$$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_Cg(z){\rm tr}(f'(z)f(z)^{-1})dz.$$
Now use the formula
$${\rm tr}(f'(z)f(z)^{-1})=\frac1{\det f(z)}\,(\det f(z))'.$$
And conclude with the formula of residues.

Remark that the formula tells us that what matters is the algebraic  multiplicities of the zeroes of $\det f$, rather than the dimension of the kernels of $f(z)$.

Comment: wow, this formula does it all, thank you. Do you have a reference or does this formula have a name?

Comment: Not especially. The differential of the determinant is just the matrix of cofactors. You might have a look at my book *Matrices*, published as a Springer-Verlag GTM **216**.